# SUM of columns in a table (JSON data) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, html-table

Couldn't find a specific answer to this so thought I'd ask. In short, I have a table that retrieves information from an API, based on data stored in my database and all I want to do is to get a total of certain, not all, columns from that table so that I can use them elsewhere on the site. As an example, let's use the Profit/Loss column and Total Divi. Do I have to somehow store the results as an array so that I can retrieve it elsewhere or is it something different?

```
<th>Profit/Loss</th>
<?php
        for($x=0;$x<$y;$x++) 
        {?>
            <tr>
                <td class="input"><?php 
                    if($pri[$x] > $lastprice[$x])
                    {
                        echo ($lastprice[$x]-$pri[$x]) * $vol[$x];
                    }
                    else if($pri[$x] < $lastprice[$x]) 
                    {
                         echo ($lastprice[$x]-$pri[$x]) * $vol[$x];
                    }
                    else
                        echo '0'; 
                    ?></td>
                 <td><?php 
                    $div = file_get_contents("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=$symbol[$x]&types=stats&filter=dividendRate");  
                    $div = json_decode($div,TRUE);  
                    foreach($div as $divi => $value) {
                    echo $value['stats']['dividendRate']; 
                    }
                    ?></td>
                <td><?php 
                    $firstno  = floatval($vol[$x]);
                    $secondno = floatval($value['stats']['dividendRate']);
                    $sum = $firstno * $secondno;
                    print ($sum);
                    ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

So I only left the profit/loss row/column as well as dividend amount (2nd column) and dividend total, just so you can see how I get these numbers in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is, you want to use the *profit/loss* and *total dividend* column data of each row at the later stage of your code. What you can do is, create an empty array before the outermost `for` loop, and in each iteration of the loop, append the  pair where key would be `$x` and value would be an array of *profit/loss* and *total dividend* column data.

```
<th>Profit/Loss</th>
<?php
    $arr = array();
    for($x=0; $x < $y; $x++){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="input">
            <?php 
                $profitOrLoss = ($lastprice[$x]-$pri[$x]) * $vol[$x];
                echo $profitOrLoss;
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php 
                $div = file_get_contents("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=$symbol[$x]&types=stats&filter=dividendRate");  
                $div = json_decode($div,TRUE); 
                $sum = 0;
                foreach($div as $divi => $value) {
                    echo $value['stats']['dividendRate']; 
                    $sum += (floatval($vol[$x]) + floatval($value['stats']['dividendRate']));
                }
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php 
                echo $sum;
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
        $arr[$x] = array('profitOrLoss' => $profitOrLoss, 'sum' => $sum);
    } 
?>
```

#### Update(1):

Based on [**your comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489039/sum-of-columns-in-a-table-json-data-in-php/48489586#comment83973226_48489586), *all I want is to add up all the rows in Profit/Loss column together as well as rows in Total Divi column together.* the solution code would be like this:

```
<th>Profit/Loss</th>
<?php
    $profitOrLossSum = 0;
    $dividendRateSum = 0;
    for($x=0; $x < $y; $x++){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="input">
            <?php 
                $profitOrLoss = ($lastprice[$x]-$pri[$x]) * $vol[$x];
                $profitOrLossSum += $profitOrLoss;
                echo $profitOrLoss;
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php 
                $div = file_get_contents("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=$symbol[$x]&types=stats&filter=dividendRate");  
                $div = json_decode($div,TRUE); 
                $sum = 0;
                foreach($div as $divi => $value) {
                    echo $value['stats']['dividendRate']; 
                    $sum += (floatval($vol[$x]) + floatval($value['stats']['dividendRate']));
                    $dividendRateSum += floatval($value['stats']['dividendRate']);
                }
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php 
                echo $sum;
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
    $arr = array('profitOrLossSum' => $profitOrLossSum, 'dividendRateSum' => $dividendRateSum);
?>
```

---

**Sidenote:** If you want to see the complete array structure, do `var_dump($arr);`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I really appreciate it! It's definitely a step in the right direction but for now, it just displays the results from the last row. So essentially, it doesn't add up all the values in that column, what would be the best way to do that? here's the var_dump if that helps: array(1) { [4]=> array(2) { ["pnl"]=> float(665) ["sum"]=> float(73) } }

Comment: @Frenzyy Can you please explain a bit more, *it just displays the results from the last row*? *it doesn't add up all the values in that column*, which column are you referring here, 2nd or 3rd?

Comment: Sorry if I explained this in a bad way, let me show you a screenshot of the table and what I want to get from it. That will probably help more and make things easier. https://imgur.com/a/HVZ0K And all I want is to add up all the rows in Profit/Loss column together as well as rows in Total Divi column together. Just so that I can use the sums from these, somewhere else on the site. In comparison to now, where by looking at the var_dump, you can tell that it's only showing results from the 4th row if you know what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: @Frenzyy I've updated my answer. Please let me know if that's what you want.

Comment: It's essentially the other way round I think because what you did essentially gives me the total for the dividend amount again for that specific row. What I want is to add up ALL those results together. Have a look at my reply above, I've also edited it. In short, how do I add 0, 0, 25.2 & 73 together? Hopefully you now understand what I mean. Thanks again!

Comment: @Frenzyy I've updated my answer, please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it really means a lot! The answer you gave in the update, gives me the correct result for the P&L column, but the dividend total is for some reason wrong. I can't figure out where these numbers are coming from and var_dump didn't help either. I tried all sorts of combinations and different variables, etc., still nothing. So, after a var_dump of the array, I get: array(2) { ["profitOrLossSum"]=> float(82880.26) ["dividendRateSum"]=> float(257.25) } which gives me the correct P&L like I said but dividendRateSum should be 98.2, yet it isn't. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: @Frenzyy Ah, there was a small bug in the code. I've updated my answer, please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!! In fact, what you did actually added up the dividend amount column, not the dividend total column but I just switched it around essentially and it works perfectly. I really appreciate your help.